# Adding class on scroll and keeping behaviour after refreshing page

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I have a perfectly functioning element that behaves as it should. Once the the user scrolls past a particular point, a class is added. When the user scrolls back up, the class is removed. My issue is that, once the class has been added, when I refresh the page, the class is no longer added until I scroll again.

This is intermittent. Firefox is the main browser that is consistently producing the issue. Chrome is on and off.

I've included a very simplified snippet of my code, however it's not easy to see as it needs a refresh. I've searched all day and looked at cookies, local storage, classie.js. I'm sure there's an easier, simpler solution than those.

Here is a website with a similar issue: https://bert.house/en/. Please check it in Firefox. The nav button on the top left of the page, scroll down and see what happens. Then refresh, you'll see that it goes back to it's original state until you scroll again.

```js
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var box = $('.box');
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 100) {
      box.removeClass('box-NotScrolled');
      box.addClass('boxScrolled');
    } else {
      if (box.hasClass('boxScrolled')) {
        box.removeClass('boxScrolled');
        box.addClass('box-NotScrolled');
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
.box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.boxScrolled {
  background-color: green;
}
.box-NotScrolled {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div style="height: 1000px"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This isn't a major issue. It's one that is bothering me as there must be a work around. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: _"I've searched all day and looked at cookies, local storage, classie.js. I'm sure there's an easier, simpler solution than those."_ Nope, that's what you'll use. CSS and HTML won't "remember" anything. I would set a localStorage item when you scroll, then read that item when the page is loaded and if it exists, add the class via JS.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It makes sense. I'll have a go at it. Not done any local storage before though. I would need to set the localStorage item when the user reaches the exact point... Do you have any recommended links I could go to? The places I've already looked at seem too advanced for what I want to do. Thanks again.

Comment: `localStorage.setItem('scrolled',true);` when a user scrolls. Then on page load `if (localStorage.getItem('scrolled')) { // addclass }`

Comment: @Jenn This shouldn't require the use of localStorage and you have most of the code already there its just that your code is not running when your script is executed. I wrote a rewrite of what you already have below that will accomplish this for you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will run when you load the script and when you scroll or resize. This will essentially check for you on page load.

```js
//Create classOnScroll function
function classOnScroll(){
  let $box = $('.box'),
      $scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  
  if($scroll > 100){
    if(!$box.hasClass('boxScrolled')) 
      $box.addClass('boxScrolled');
  }
  else
    $box.removeClass('boxScrolled');

}

//Run on first site run
classOnScroll();

//Run on scroll and resize
$(window).on('scroll resize',classOnScroll);
```

```css
.box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.boxScrolled {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div style="height: 1000px"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is great. Works perfectly! Thanks so much, I'm surprised I couldn't find a simple solution like this when I was looking.

Answer (score 0):

> "I've searched all day and looked at cookies, local storage, classie.js. I'm sure there's an easier, simpler solution than those."

Nope, that's what you'll use. CSS and HTML can't "remember" anything. You can set a `localStorage` item when the user scrolls, then on page load, check for that item, and if it exists, add the class via JS.

And since `localStorage` doesn't work in the sandbox environment for posts on SO, here's a codepen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLmgPw

```js
$(function() {
  var box = $('.box');
  function setScrolled() {
    box.removeClass('box-NotScrolled');
    box.addClass('boxScrolled');
    localStorage.setItem('scrolled',true);
  }
  function removeScrolled() {
    if (box.hasClass('boxScrolled')) {
      box.removeClass('boxScrolled');
      box.addClass('box-NotScrolled');
    }
  }
  if (localStorage.getItem('scrolled')) {
    setScrolled();
  }
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 100) {
      setScrolled();
    } else {
      removeScrolled();
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.boxScrolled {
  background-color: green;
}
.box-NotScrolled {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<div style="height: 1000px"></div>
```

Comment: The trouble with this is that if its reading from local storage it is set to true irrespective of the scroll location on refresh as that value isn't validated.Take a look at my code example above, this will validate the scroll position for her on refresh and set the class accordingly.